# Simple Javascript modification to return the output multiplied by a specific number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on this nutrition calculator for a while now and am looking to create another output at the bottom of the page displaying the original output * 365 to calculate the difference you'd be making if you replaced the item every year.

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/j1td52y9/1/

```js
var  stocks= [
  ["Beef (80/20) raw","oz",115.4451262,2.094125,1.199617347,72,4.85,5.65,0,2.142,19,20,0.0001275510204,0.375,0.75,22.15988372,0.3768292943,4  ],
  ["Beef (90/10) raw","oz",115.4451262,2.094125,1.199617347,50,5.65,2.83,0,1.109,19,18,0.0001275510204,0.375,0.75,22.15988372,0.3768292943,4  ],
  ["Chicken breast","oz",32.39053977,0.320375,0.07197704082,34,6.38,0.74,0,0.16,13,21,0.01631172356,0.10625,0.2125,3.149953226,0.3765300698,4  ],
  ["Chicken thighs/legs","oz",32.39053977,0.320375,0.07197704082,125,2.72,12.54,0,3.431,14,30,0.01631172356,0.10625,0.2125,3.149953226,0.3765799405,4  ],
  ["Milk (whole)","fl oz",7.638924987,0.146025,0.0002099330357,19,0.96,0.99,1.54,0.569,13,3,3.571428571e-7,0.099609375,0.19921875,1.228661955,0.2415694159,8  ],
  ["Milk (2%)","fl oz",7.638924987,0.06112164455,0.0002099330357,15,1.06,0.58,1.54,0.363,16,2,3.571428571e-7,0.099609375,0.19921875,1.228661955,0.2417190282,8  ],
  ["Pizza (cheese)","slice",42,0.9700347449,0.006297991071,285,12.19,10.37,3.83,4.778,640,18,0.00001071428571,2.98828125,5.9765625,36.85985865,0.466697922,4  ],
  ["Ice Cream","cup",32.59312,0.6168324833,0.002345956329,274.71344,4.6095984,14.4806576,27.9835216,8.94913952,107.09168,55.87392,0.000003990994286,1.11311325,2.2262265,13.73003196,2.889031735,1  ],
  ["Milk (skim)","fl oz",7.638924987,0.05927058824,0.0002099330357,10,1.03,0.02,1.54,0.017,13,1,3.571428571e-7,0.099609375,0.19921875,1.228661955,0.2415694159,8  ],
  ["Eggs (large)","each",43.13341461,0.514206,0.007354326122,78,6.29,5.3,0.2,1.633,62,186,0.001666666667,0.265625,0.53125,3.713549,0.1305756192,1  ],
  ["Lamb","oz",78.125,2.8105,1.199617347,80,4.69,6.64,0,2.889,17,21,0.03333333333,0.3125,0.625,2.274815967,0.3767295528,4  ],
  ["Cheese (hard)","slice (oz)",37.44571072,1.35025,0.002099330357,105,6.59,8.41,0.14,5.32,159,27,0.000003571428571,0.99609375,1.9921875,12.28661955,0.1303337926,1  ],
  ["Yogurt","oz",5.833333333,0.09375,0.0002099330357,17,0.98,0.92,1.32,0.595,13,4,3.571428571e-7,0.099609375,0.19921875,1.228661955,0.2229453548,6  ],
  ["Greek yogurt, vanilla (nonfat)","fl oz",15,0.08232711306,0.0005248325893,22,2.45,0.05,1.01,0.038,10,1,8.928571429e-7,0.3984375,0.796875,3.071654888,0.1965527472,6  ],
  ["Chocolate","oz",127.316,0.1862906,0.00004198660714,151,2.16,8.39,14.57,5.238,22,7,7.142857143e-8,0.019921875,0.03984375,1.601963425,1.345070603,1.45  ],
  ["Cacao","oz",179.739,0.625,0,136,1.19,8.51,15.45,5.032,3,0,0,0,0,3.390577585,1.418619303,1.45  ],
  ["Salmon (farmed)","oz",0.498125,0.56925,0,59,5.79,3.8,0,0.864,17,16,0.004464285714,0.078125,0.15625,0.5593288054,0.3767295528,4  ],
  ["Tuna (canned in oil)","oz",0.498125,0.1197485281,0,56,8.26,2.33,0,0.435,118,5,0.000270197828,1.0625,2.125,0.5593288054,0.3817664985,4  ],
  ["Mayo","oz",14.41309121,0.121875,0.001838581531,193,0.27,21.22,0.16,3.318,180,12,0.0004166666667,0.06640625,0.1328125,0.92838725,0.1330741748,0.5  ],
  ["Pulled Pork raw","oz",44.84498316,0.63525,0.1411314526,53,4.94,3.5,0,1.232,17,18,0.0005208333333,0.21875,0.4375,1.592371177,0.3767295528,4  ],
  ["Butter (salted)","oz",41.58720633,0.5875,0.00440859375,203,0.24,22.95,0.02,14.537,182,61,0.0000075,2.091796875,4.18359375,25.80190106,0.121322241,1  ],
  ["Soy Burger","oz",21.8,0.048125,0,50,4.44,1.78,0.3,0.408,161,1,0,0,0,2.314125,0.03342563782,4  ],
  ["Vegan Nuggets (soy)","oz",21.8,0.048125,0,52,4.88,1.63,0.65,0.325,172,0,0,0,0,2.314125,0.06360340429,4  ],
  ["Soymilk (original)","fl oz",2.319532348,0.02445449777,0,17,1,0.54,1.21,0.063,16,0,0,0,0,1.168382863,0.1032302684,8  ],
  ["Tofu","oz",25.25,0.09625,0,23,2.82,1.49,0.2,0.26,1,0,0,0,0,4.62825,0.01698083545,4  ],
  ["Tempeh","oz",12.383064,0.0230998152,0,54,5.74,3.06,0,0.719,3,0,0,0,0,1.110771114,0.0001496122504,4  ],
  ["Mixed Nuts","oz",18.72285536,0.18425,0,172,5.53,15.17,1.42,2.271,1,1,0,0,0,1.019662873,0.1202597201,1  ],
  ["Bread","slice",9.735884788,0.1530147137,0,79,3.09,1.31,1.66,0.202,137,0,0,0,0,0.5625,0.1473592997,2  ],
  ["Lentils","oz",30.3684714,0.07425,0,33,2.55,0.11,0.51,0.015,1,0,0,0,0,2.287814892,0.04322383072,7.1  ],
  ["Black Beans","oz",30.3684714,0.141625,0,37,2.31,0.1,0.09,0.025,1,0,0,0,0,1.555714169,0.007668804863,7.1  ],
  ["Tomato Sauce","oz",3.13704,0.09375,0,11,0.47,0.06,1.37,0.008,57,0,0,0,0,0.4188459746,0.1188197409,8  ],
  ["Pinto Beans","oz",30.3684714,0.141625,0,40,2.55,0.18,0.09,0.038,0,0,0,0,0,0.9075003086,0.007618934113,7.1  ],
  ["French Fries","oz",2.9337142,0.0417335921,0,56,0.82,1.91,0.14,0.359,113,0,0,0,0,0.4200133922,0.01748707005,4  ],
  ["Peanut Butter","oz",36,0.2145,0,167,6.81,14.13,2.97,2.153,138,0,0,0,0,3.675378676,0.2583069893,1  ],
  ["Olive Oil","oz",21.77842536,0.2306145384,0,250,0,28.3,0,3.908,1,0,0,0,0,1.512500057,0.00004987075014,0.5  ],
  ["Banana"," medium",6.440662244,0.1763699536,0,105,1.29,0.39,14.43,0.132,1,0,0,0,0,0.1768995697,1.221618974,1  ],
  ["Mixed vegetables","oz",2.41150377,0.125,0,18,0.81,0.04,0,0.009,10,0,0,0,0,3,0.0004987075014,4  ],
  ["Nutritional Yeast","g",0.08506329224,0.00706361088,0,3.9859577,0.5989518739,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5  ],
  ["Rice (white)","oz",25.46308329,0.34375,0,102,1.87,0.16,0,0.045,0,0,0,0,0,0.3995205753,0,2  ],
  ["Potatoes","oz",1.872285536,0.03575,0,16,0.73,0.03,0.2,0.007,3,0,0,0,0,0.06927480776,0.01708057695,5.3  ],
  ["Vegetable Oil","oz",17.70433203,0.125,0,205,0,23.8,0,19.937,0,0,0,0,0,5.300817694,0,0.5  ],
  ["Wheat (flour)","cup",40.44136758,0.1235081329,0,408,13.56,1.88,0.36,0.276,4,0,0,0,0,1.598082301,0.03067521945,0.25  ],
  ["Margarine","oz",9.915624199,0.06125,0,102,0.28,11.32,0,2.048,222,0,0,0,0,5.300817694,0.01107130653,1  ],
  ["Corn Syrup","fl oz",11.15931776,0.01728062914,0,109,0,0,29.31,0,1,0,0,0,0,0.4854914297,2.481282747,1  ],
  ["Sugar","oz",11.23371322,0.01503093504,0,110,0,0,28.3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.4340729937,2.395731504,1  ],
  ["Corn (grain)","oz",6.74022793,0.0104375,0,103,2.67,1.34,0.18,0.189,10,0,0,0,0,0.4549631935,0.01573657573,1  ],
  ["Soda","fl oz",10.64647779,0.02494335117,0,13,0,0.08,3.05,0,1,0,0,0,0,0.1939638153,0.2582470824,12  ]
]
function Stock (data) {
  return {
    name: data[0],
    servingUnit: data[1],
    water: [data[2], ''],
    carbon: [data[3], ''],
    methane: [data[4], ''],
    calories: [data[5], ''],
    protein: [data[6], 'g'],
    fat: [data[7], 'g'],
    saturatedFat: [data[9], 'g'],
    sugar: [data[8], 'g'],
    sodium: [data[10], 'mg'],
    cholesterol: [data[11], 'mg'],
    lives: [data[12], ''],
    feed: [data[13], ''],
    meals: [data[14], ''],
    land : [data[15], ''],
    healthcare : [data[16], ''],
    unitsPerServing: data[data.length - 1]
  }
}

stocks = stocks.map(Stock)

var $selects = $('.selectStock')
var $quantity = $('#numberOfStocks')
var $comparisonResult = $('.comparison .result')

$selects.each(function() {
  $(this).append(stocks.map(function(stock, i) {
    return new Option(stock.name, i)
  }))
})

function format(data, multiplier, digits,a) {
  data = data.slice()
  data[0] = (+(data[0] * multiplier).toFixed(digits)).toLocaleString();
    console.log(data);
  if(a=="bad" && data[2]=="more"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-red'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  if(a=="bad" && data[2]=="less"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-green'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  else if (a=="good" && data[2]=="less"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-red'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  else if (a=="good" && data[2]=="more"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-green'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  return data.join(' ')
}

function stockFacts(stock, quantity) {
  return [
    format(stock.water, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' gallons of water<br>' +
    format(stock.carbon, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' pounds of carbon dioxide <br>' +
    format(stock.methane, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' carbon-equivalent pounds of methane<br>' +
    format(stock.calories, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' calories<br>' +
    format(stock.protein, quantity, 2,"good") + ' of protein<br>' +
    format(stock.fat, quantity, 3,"bad") + ' of fat<br>' +
    format(stock.saturatedFat, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' of saturated fat<br>' +
    format(stock.sugar, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' of sugar<br>' +
    format(stock.sodium, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' of sodium<br>' +
    format(stock.cholesterol, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' of cholesterol<br>' +
    format(stock.lives, quantity, 5,"bad") + ' animal lives<br>' +
    format(stock.feed, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' pounds of feed<br>' +
    format(stock.meals, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' meals made from feed<br>' +
    format(stock.land, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' square feet of land needed<br>' +
    "$"+format(stock.healthcare, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' in projected healthcare costs<br>'
  ]
}

$selects.add($quantity).on('input', updateAmount)

function getStock (select) {
  return stocks[+select.value]
}

function updateAmount() {
  var quantity = +$quantity.val() 
    
  $selects.each(function() {
    var $result = $(this).nextAll('.result').empty()
    var $amount = $(this).prev().find('.servingUnit').empty()
    var stock = getStock(this)
    if (!stock) return
    var amount = quantity * stock.unitsPerServing
    
    $amount.text(' (' + amount + ' ' + stock.servingUnit + ')')
    
    $result.html(stockFacts(stock, amount))
  })
  
  var selected = [].map.call($selects, getStock)
  $comparisonResult.empty()
  if (!selected[0] || !selected[1]) return
  var diff = {}
  Object.keys(selected[0]).forEach(function (k) {
    if (/^(name|servingUnit|unitsPerServing)$/.test(k)) return
    var first = selected[0][k].slice()
    var second = selected[1][k].slice()
    first[0] *= selected[0].unitsPerServing
    second[0] *= selected[1].unitsPerServing
    diff[k] = [Math.abs(first[0] - second[0]), first[1], first[0] > second[0] ? 'more' : 'less']
  })
  $comparisonResult.html(stockFacts(diff, quantity))
}

$selects.add($quantity).on('input', updateAmount)

function getStock (select) {
  return stocks[+select.value]
}

function updateAmount2() {
  var quantity = +$quantity.val() 
    
  $selects.each(function() {
    var $result = $(this).nextAll('.result').empty()
    var $amount2 = $(this).prev().find('.servingUnit').empty()
    var stock = getStock(this)
    if (!stock) return
    var amount2 = quantity * stock.unitsPerServing* (365) 
    
    $amount2.text(' (' + amount2 + ' ' + stock.servingUnit + ')')
    
    $result.html(stockFacts(stock, amount2))
  })
  
  var selected = [].map.call($selects, getStock)
  $comparisonResult.empty()
  if (!selected[0] || !selected[1]) return
  var diff = {}
  Object.keys(selected[0]).forEach(function (k) {
    if (/^(name|servingUnit|unitsPerServing)$/.test(k)) return
    var first = selected[0][k].slice()
    var second = selected[1][k].slice()
    first[0] *= selected[0].unitsPerServing
    second[0] *= selected[1].unitsPerServing
    diff[k] = [Math.abs(first[0] - second[0]), first[1], first[0] > second[0] ? 'more' : 'less']
  })
  $comparisonResult2.html(stockFacts(diff, quantity))
}
```

```css
.side {
  width: 300px;
}
.sideone {
  width: 300px;
}
h2
{
  display: inline-block;
}
.left
{
  float: right;
}
.comparison {
width: 50%;
}
.outer {
 display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.content
{
  width: 50%;
}
.color-red{
color:red;
background:transparent}
.color-green{
color:green;
background:transparent}

div {
background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    Servings:
    <input type="number" id="numberOfStocks" value="1" min="0" />
  </label>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="side">
        <h2>First Item<span class="servingUnit"></span>:</h2>
        <select class="selectStock">
          <option value="-1">Pick a food!</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="sideone">
        <h2>Second Item<span class="servingUnit"></span>:</h2>
        <select class="selectStock">
          <option value="-1">Pick a food!</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comparison">
      <h2>Comparison:</h2>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="result"></div>
  </div> 
</div>
<br>
<h2>If you swapped choices every day for a year, you would:</h2>
```

Note that I tried to approach this by simply replicating the original code and multiplying it by 365, but that didn't seem to work and I can't figure out why. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: could you please add comments describing where exactly the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?
If you already have the final output as

```
$comparisonResult.html(stockFacts(diff, quantity));
```

then just use this to get the year result:

```
$('#year_result').html(stockFacts(diff, quantity*365));
```

And output it into:

```
<div id="year_result">
</div>
```

I removed your `updateAmount2` since you don't need to recalculate everything one more time.

```js
var  stocks= [
  ["Beef (80/20) raw","oz",115.4451262,2.094125,1.199617347,72,4.85,5.65,0,2.142,19,20,0.0001275510204,0.375,0.75,22.15988372,0.3768292943,4  ],
  ["Beef (90/10) raw","oz",115.4451262,2.094125,1.199617347,50,5.65,2.83,0,1.109,19,18,0.0001275510204,0.375,0.75,22.15988372,0.3768292943,4  ],
  ["Chicken breast","oz",32.39053977,0.320375,0.07197704082,34,6.38,0.74,0,0.16,13,21,0.01631172356,0.10625,0.2125,3.149953226,0.3765300698,4  ],
  ["Chicken thighs/legs","oz",32.39053977,0.320375,0.07197704082,125,2.72,12.54,0,3.431,14,30,0.01631172356,0.10625,0.2125,3.149953226,0.3765799405,4  ],
  ["Milk (whole)","fl oz",7.638924987,0.146025,0.0002099330357,19,0.96,0.99,1.54,0.569,13,3,3.571428571e-7,0.099609375,0.19921875,1.228661955,0.2415694159,8  ],
  ["Milk (2%)","fl oz",7.638924987,0.06112164455,0.0002099330357,15,1.06,0.58,1.54,0.363,16,2,3.571428571e-7,0.099609375,0.19921875,1.228661955,0.2417190282,8  ],
  ["Pizza (cheese)","slice",42,0.9700347449,0.006297991071,285,12.19,10.37,3.83,4.778,640,18,0.00001071428571,2.98828125,5.9765625,36.85985865,0.466697922,4  ],
  ["Ice Cream","cup",32.59312,0.6168324833,0.002345956329,274.71344,4.6095984,14.4806576,27.9835216,8.94913952,107.09168,55.87392,0.000003990994286,1.11311325,2.2262265,13.73003196,2.889031735,1  ],
  ["Milk (skim)","fl oz",7.638924987,0.05927058824,0.0002099330357,10,1.03,0.02,1.54,0.017,13,1,3.571428571e-7,0.099609375,0.19921875,1.228661955,0.2415694159,8  ],
  ["Eggs (large)","each",43.13341461,0.514206,0.007354326122,78,6.29,5.3,0.2,1.633,62,186,0.001666666667,0.265625,0.53125,3.713549,0.1305756192,1  ],
  ["Lamb","oz",78.125,2.8105,1.199617347,80,4.69,6.64,0,2.889,17,21,0.03333333333,0.3125,0.625,2.274815967,0.3767295528,4  ],
  ["Cheese (hard)","slice (oz)",37.44571072,1.35025,0.002099330357,105,6.59,8.41,0.14,5.32,159,27,0.000003571428571,0.99609375,1.9921875,12.28661955,0.1303337926,1  ],
  ["Yogurt","oz",5.833333333,0.09375,0.0002099330357,17,0.98,0.92,1.32,0.595,13,4,3.571428571e-7,0.099609375,0.19921875,1.228661955,0.2229453548,6  ],
  ["Greek yogurt, vanilla (nonfat)","fl oz",15,0.08232711306,0.0005248325893,22,2.45,0.05,1.01,0.038,10,1,8.928571429e-7,0.3984375,0.796875,3.071654888,0.1965527472,6  ],
  ["Chocolate","oz",127.316,0.1862906,0.00004198660714,151,2.16,8.39,14.57,5.238,22,7,7.142857143e-8,0.019921875,0.03984375,1.601963425,1.345070603,1.45  ],
  ["Cacao","oz",179.739,0.625,0,136,1.19,8.51,15.45,5.032,3,0,0,0,0,3.390577585,1.418619303,1.45  ],
  ["Salmon (farmed)","oz",0.498125,0.56925,0,59,5.79,3.8,0,0.864,17,16,0.004464285714,0.078125,0.15625,0.5593288054,0.3767295528,4  ],
  ["Tuna (canned in oil)","oz",0.498125,0.1197485281,0,56,8.26,2.33,0,0.435,118,5,0.000270197828,1.0625,2.125,0.5593288054,0.3817664985,4  ],
  ["Mayo","oz",14.41309121,0.121875,0.001838581531,193,0.27,21.22,0.16,3.318,180,12,0.0004166666667,0.06640625,0.1328125,0.92838725,0.1330741748,0.5  ],
  ["Pulled Pork raw","oz",44.84498316,0.63525,0.1411314526,53,4.94,3.5,0,1.232,17,18,0.0005208333333,0.21875,0.4375,1.592371177,0.3767295528,4  ],
  ["Butter (salted)","oz",41.58720633,0.5875,0.00440859375,203,0.24,22.95,0.02,14.537,182,61,0.0000075,2.091796875,4.18359375,25.80190106,0.121322241,1  ],
  ["Soy Burger","oz",21.8,0.048125,0,50,4.44,1.78,0.3,0.408,161,1,0,0,0,2.314125,0.03342563782,4  ],
  ["Vegan Nuggets (soy)","oz",21.8,0.048125,0,52,4.88,1.63,0.65,0.325,172,0,0,0,0,2.314125,0.06360340429,4  ],
  ["Soymilk (original)","fl oz",2.319532348,0.02445449777,0,17,1,0.54,1.21,0.063,16,0,0,0,0,1.168382863,0.1032302684,8  ],
  ["Tofu","oz",25.25,0.09625,0,23,2.82,1.49,0.2,0.26,1,0,0,0,0,4.62825,0.01698083545,4  ],
  ["Tempeh","oz",12.383064,0.0230998152,0,54,5.74,3.06,0,0.719,3,0,0,0,0,1.110771114,0.0001496122504,4  ],
  ["Mixed Nuts","oz",18.72285536,0.18425,0,172,5.53,15.17,1.42,2.271,1,1,0,0,0,1.019662873,0.1202597201,1  ],
  ["Bread","slice",9.735884788,0.1530147137,0,79,3.09,1.31,1.66,0.202,137,0,0,0,0,0.5625,0.1473592997,2  ],
  ["Lentils","oz",30.3684714,0.07425,0,33,2.55,0.11,0.51,0.015,1,0,0,0,0,2.287814892,0.04322383072,7.1  ],
  ["Black Beans","oz",30.3684714,0.141625,0,37,2.31,0.1,0.09,0.025,1,0,0,0,0,1.555714169,0.007668804863,7.1  ],
  ["Tomato Sauce","oz",3.13704,0.09375,0,11,0.47,0.06,1.37,0.008,57,0,0,0,0,0.4188459746,0.1188197409,8  ],
  ["Pinto Beans","oz",30.3684714,0.141625,0,40,2.55,0.18,0.09,0.038,0,0,0,0,0,0.9075003086,0.007618934113,7.1  ],
  ["French Fries","oz",2.9337142,0.0417335921,0,56,0.82,1.91,0.14,0.359,113,0,0,0,0,0.4200133922,0.01748707005,4  ],
  ["Peanut Butter","oz",36,0.2145,0,167,6.81,14.13,2.97,2.153,138,0,0,0,0,3.675378676,0.2583069893,1  ],
  ["Olive Oil","oz",21.77842536,0.2306145384,0,250,0,28.3,0,3.908,1,0,0,0,0,1.512500057,0.00004987075014,0.5  ],
  ["Banana"," medium",6.440662244,0.1763699536,0,105,1.29,0.39,14.43,0.132,1,0,0,0,0,0.1768995697,1.221618974,1  ],
  ["Mixed vegetables","oz",2.41150377,0.125,0,18,0.81,0.04,0,0.009,10,0,0,0,0,3,0.0004987075014,4  ],
  ["Nutritional Yeast","g",0.08506329224,0.00706361088,0,3.9859577,0.5989518739,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5  ],
  ["Rice (white)","oz",25.46308329,0.34375,0,102,1.87,0.16,0,0.045,0,0,0,0,0,0.3995205753,0,2  ],
  ["Potatoes","oz",1.872285536,0.03575,0,16,0.73,0.03,0.2,0.007,3,0,0,0,0,0.06927480776,0.01708057695,5.3  ],
  ["Vegetable Oil","oz",17.70433203,0.125,0,205,0,23.8,0,19.937,0,0,0,0,0,5.300817694,0,0.5  ],
  ["Wheat (flour)","cup",40.44136758,0.1235081329,0,408,13.56,1.88,0.36,0.276,4,0,0,0,0,1.598082301,0.03067521945,0.25  ],
  ["Margarine","oz",9.915624199,0.06125,0,102,0.28,11.32,0,2.048,222,0,0,0,0,5.300817694,0.01107130653,1  ],
  ["Corn Syrup","fl oz",11.15931776,0.01728062914,0,109,0,0,29.31,0,1,0,0,0,0,0.4854914297,2.481282747,1  ],
  ["Sugar","oz",11.23371322,0.01503093504,0,110,0,0,28.3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.4340729937,2.395731504,1  ],
  ["Corn (grain)","oz",6.74022793,0.0104375,0,103,2.67,1.34,0.18,0.189,10,0,0,0,0,0.4549631935,0.01573657573,1  ],
  ["Soda","fl oz",10.64647779,0.02494335117,0,13,0,0.08,3.05,0,1,0,0,0,0,0.1939638153,0.2582470824,12  ]
]
function Stock (data) {
  return {
    name: data[0],
    servingUnit: data[1],
    water: [data[2], ''],
    carbon: [data[3], ''],
    methane: [data[4], ''],
    calories: [data[5], ''],
    protein: [data[6], 'g'],
    fat: [data[7], 'g'],
    saturatedFat: [data[9], 'g'],
    sugar: [data[8], 'g'],
    sodium: [data[10], 'mg'],
    cholesterol: [data[11], 'mg'],
    lives: [data[12], ''],
    feed: [data[13], ''],
    meals: [data[14], ''],
    land : [data[15], ''],
    healthcare : [data[16], ''],
    unitsPerServing: data[data.length - 1]
  }
}

stocks = stocks.map(Stock)

var $selects = $('.selectStock')
var $quantity = $('#numberOfStocks')
var $comparisonResult = $('.comparison .result')

$selects.each(function() {
  $(this).append(stocks.map(function(stock, i) {
    return new Option(stock.name, i)
  }))
})

function format(data, multiplier, digits,a) {
  data = data.slice()
  data[0] = (+(data[0] * multiplier).toFixed(digits)).toLocaleString();
    console.log(data);
  if(a=="bad" && data[2]=="more"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-red'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  if(a=="bad" && data[2]=="less"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-green'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  else if (a=="good" && data[2]=="less"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-red'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  else if (a=="good" && data[2]=="more"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-green'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  return data.join(' ')
}

function stockFacts(stock, quantity) {
  return [
    format(stock.water, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' gallons of water<br>' +
    format(stock.carbon, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' pounds of carbon dioxide <br>' +
    format(stock.methane, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' carbon-equivalent pounds of methane<br>' +
    format(stock.calories, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' calories<br>' +
    format(stock.protein, quantity, 2,"good") + ' of protein<br>' +
    format(stock.fat, quantity, 3,"bad") + ' of fat<br>' +
    format(stock.saturatedFat, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' of saturated fat<br>' +
    format(stock.sugar, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' of sugar<br>' +
    format(stock.sodium, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' of sodium<br>' +
    format(stock.cholesterol, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' of cholesterol<br>' +
    format(stock.lives, quantity, 5,"bad") + ' animal lives<br>' +
    format(stock.feed, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' pounds of feed<br>' +
    format(stock.meals, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' meals made from feed<br>' +
    format(stock.land, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' square feet of land needed<br>' +
    "$"+format(stock.healthcare, quantity, 2,"bad") + ' in projected healthcare costs<br>'
  ]
}

$selects.add($quantity).on('input', updateAmount)

function getStock (select) {
  return stocks[+select.value]
}

function updateAmount() {
  var quantity = +$quantity.val() 
    
  $selects.each(function() {
    var $result = $(this).nextAll('.result').empty()
    var $amount = $(this).prev().find('.servingUnit').empty()
    var stock = getStock(this)
    if (!stock) return
    var amount = quantity * stock.unitsPerServing
    
    $amount.text(' (' + amount + ' ' + stock.servingUnit + ')')
    
    $result.html(stockFacts(stock, amount))
  })
  
  var selected = [].map.call($selects, getStock)
  $comparisonResult.empty()
  if (!selected[0] || !selected[1]) return
  var diff = {}
  Object.keys(selected[0]).forEach(function (k) {
    if (/^(name|servingUnit|unitsPerServing)$/.test(k)) return
    var first = selected[0][k].slice()
    var second = selected[1][k].slice()
    first[0] *= selected[0].unitsPerServing
    second[0] *= selected[1].unitsPerServing
    diff[k] = [Math.abs(first[0] - second[0]), first[1], first[0] > second[0] ? 'more' : 'less']
  })
  $comparisonResult.html(stockFacts(diff, quantity));
 
 $('#year_result').html(stockFacts(diff, quantity*365));
}

$selects.add($quantity).on('input', updateAmount)

function getStock (select) {
  return stocks[+select.value]
}
```

```css
.side {
  width: 300px;
}
.sideone {
  width: 300px;
}
h2
{
  display: inline-block;
}
.left
{
  float: right;
}
.comparison {
width: 50%;
}
.outer {
 display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.content
{
  width: 50%;
}
.color-red{
color:red;
background:transparent}
.color-green{
color:green;
background:transparent}

div {
background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    Servings:
    <input type="number" id="numberOfStocks" value="1" min="0" />
  </label>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="side">
        <h2>First Item<span class="servingUnit"></span>:</h2>
        <select class="selectStock">
          <option value="-1">Pick a food!</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="sideone">
        <h2>Second Item<span class="servingUnit"></span>:</h2>
        <select class="selectStock">
          <option value="-1">Pick a food!</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comparison">
      <h2>Comparison:</h2>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="result"></div>
  </div> 
</div>
<br>
<h2>If you swapped choices every day for a year, you would:</h2>
<div id="year_result">
</div>
```

Comment: That is awesome, thanks a lot! One thing I should have mentioned before is I'd need to adjust the wording a bit in the second part so that it makes sense. Was thinking something like "use x less gallons of water" for certain items and "get x less protein" for certain items. I already did something like this with the "bad" and "good" sections, do you know how I would go about doing this? Was thinking of basically replicating the code, but assigning 2 different keys to the variables (use for water, carbon, methane and get for protein, calories, fat, etc) and then creating another format function

Comment: @DickThompson you could always create the similar function (for example call it updateAmount2) and call it at the end of updateAmount?  (ex: `updateAmount2();`)

Comment: so I would nest this in the original updateAmount function?

Comment: @DickThompson if you need the different word, add another function like this one `stockFacts2(stock, quantity)` for the special item you are comparing, you can put different words inside that function,  then call `$comparisonResult.html(stockFacts2(diff, quantity));` to update.

Comment: @DickThompson give a try, and if that does not work, you can always create another question post, someone would take a look and able to help you

Comment: Hey I figured it out, I simply just had to make a different stockfacts like you said with my updated jargon, and it all worked. I'm having some trouble with the wording (I need some stuff to say less when it currently says more because of the way the code is written), but I'll post that in another question. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @DickThompson Nice, happy to help!